# webpack does not actually create any bundle file

Tags: webpack

I can't get webpack to actually generate the output file. I can run `webpack` and I get **webpack: bundle is now VALID** with no errors but no file is ever created. I have tried changing my output directory too, nothing seems to work.

I have read many posts addressing the same issue but nobody has been able to figure this mystery out. Example webpack config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack'),
path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    debug: true,
    entry: {
    main: './assets/js/components/test.js'
  },

  output: {
    path: path.join('./dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you include the command you use to execute webpack?

Comment: The command is `webpack`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some trial and error the solution ended up being that I needed to run `webpack` from the package.json by adding it as a script. Still don't understand why I can't just run `webpack` from the Terminal. Anyone know why it has to be a script like this?

`"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack"
  },`

and then run this command in Terminal:

`npm start`

Answer (score 2):

According to https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-path

> The output directory as an **absolute path** (required).

Have you tried the following for your output path?

```
path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't seem to do anything for me. I was able to answer my issue by putting `webpack` as a npm script.

Comment: And don't forget to put the `var path = require('path');` at the beggining of your webpack.config.js